# geth init, what are the arguments?

Tags: go-ethereum

this command works but yields a warning of future removal so I'd like to use new option `init` :

```
➜  ~ go-ethereum/build/bin/geth --datadir="~/testgeth/" --genesis ~/testgeth/customgenesis.json --port "30304" --networkid 6776 --rpc --rpccorsdomain="http://localhost:63342" --rpcport="8546" --minerthreads="1" --nodiscover --maxpeers=0 console

####################################################################
#                                                                  #
# --genesis is deprecated. Switch to use 'geth init /path/to/file' #
#                                                                  #
####################################################################
```

unfortunately the help isn't very verbose :

```
➜  ~ go-ethereum/build/bin/geth init --help
init [arguments...]

The init command initialises a new genesis block and definition for the network.
This is a destructive action and changes the network in which you will be
participating.
```

I tried that but it yields an error :

```
➜  ~ go-ethereum/build/bin/geth init testgeth/customgenesis.json --datadir="~/testgeth/" --port "30304" --networkid 6776 --rpc --rpccorsdomain="http://localhost:63342" --rpcport="8546" --minerthreads="1" --nodiscover --maxpeers=0 console
Incorrect Usage.

init [arguments...]

The init command initialises a new genesis block and definition for the network.
This is a destructive action and changes the network in which you will be
participating.


flag provided but not defined: -datadir
```

Comment: What version of geth are you using?

Comment: try `geth --datadir="~/testgethnew/"` make sure to run `mkdir ~/testgethnew` before that.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah develop one, 1.4.0-unstable.

Comment: @NikhilM the directories are fine, the deprecated command works perfectly, 1st one I wrote in my question in fact

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move the --datadir "~/testgeth/" parameter before the init {customgenesis-path} parameter and it will work.

This init parameter is new, in the develop branch version 1.4.0 .

From https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/develop/cmd/geth/main.go#L440-L461 :

```
// initGenesis will initialise the given JSON format genesis file and writes it as
// the zero'd block (i.e. genesis) or will fail hard if it can't succeed.
func initGenesis(ctx *cli.Context) {
    genesisPath := ctx.Args().First()
    if len(genesisPath) == 0 {
            utils.Fatalf("must supply path to genesis JSON file")
    }

    chainDb, err := ethdb.NewLDBDatabase(filepath.Join(utils.MustMakeDataDir(ctx), "chaindata"), 0, 0)
    if err != nil {
            utils.Fatalf("could not open database: %v", err)
    }

    genesisFile, err := os.Open(genesisPath)
    if err != nil {
            utils.Fatalf("failed to read genesis file: %v", err)
    }

    block, err := core.WriteGenesisBlock(chainDb, genesisFile)
    if err != nil {
            utils.Fatalf("failed to write genesis block: %v", err)
    }
    glog.V(logger.Info).Infof("successfully wrote genesis block and/or chain rule set: %x", block.Hash())
}
```

From https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/develop/cmd/utils/flags.go#L387-L399 :

```
// MustMakeDataDir retrieves the currently requested data directory, terminating
// if none (or the empty string) is specified. If the node is starting a testnet,
// the a subdirectory of the specified datadir will be used.
func MustMakeDataDir(ctx *cli.Context) string {
    if path := ctx.GlobalString(DataDirFlag.Name); path != "" {
            if ctx.GlobalBool(TestNetFlag.Name) {
                    return filepath.Join(path, "/testnet")
            }
            return path
    }
    Fatalf("Cannot determine default data directory, please set manually (--datadir)")
    return ""
}
```

---

### Update 20/07/2016

From [`geth` Command Line Options - Init](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options#init):

> **Init**
>
> With the init command it is possible to create a chain with a custom genesis block and chain configuration (currently only the homestead transition block can be configured). It respects the `--datadir` argument and accepts a JSON file describing the chain configuration.
>
> ```
> geth --datadir <some/location/where/to/create/chain> init genesis.json
> ```
>
> Example genesis.json file:
>
> ```
> {
>     "config": {
>             "homesteadBlock": "10"
>     },
>     "nonce": "0",
>     "difficulty": "0x20000",
>     "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
>     "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>     "timestamp": "0x00",
>     "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>     "extraData": "0x",
>     "gasLimit": "0x2FEFD8",
>     "alloc": {}
> }
> ```
>
> To use the created chain start geth with:
>
> ```
> geth --datadir <some/location/where/to/create/chain>
> ```

Comment: `go-ethereum/build/bin/geth init testgeth/customgenesis.json --datadir ~/testgeth` with or without quotes around the datadir directory yields the same error: flag provided but not defined: -datadir

Comment: `go-ethereum/build/bin/geth init testgeth/customgenesis.json datadir="~/testgeth"` is a little bit better : I0404 16:54:55.024842 ethdb/database.go:82] Alloted 16MB cache and 16 file handles to /home/lotso/.ethereum/chaindata
Fatal: could not open database: resource temporarily unavailable
seems like a bug handling arguments in the init command to me

Comment: use the --datadir '{directory}' before the init parameter and it works.

Comment: mmmm you're right the --datadir and other -- args apply to geth ! thanks

Comment: As a side note: Be very careful running `init`.  If you forget to set the datadir you will overwrite you existing chaindata!