# Geth --genesis is giving Invalid Usage

Tags: go-ethereum

I am following this [link](https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html) to make private Ethereum Chain.But running

```
geth --identity "Prashant" --genesis CustomGenesis.json --rpc --rpcport "8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "chaindata" --port "30303" --nodiscover --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --autodag --networkid 1900 --nat "any" console
```

gives **Incorrect Usage.**

I am using stable version of geth 1.4.10.

What's the possible reasons for the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most likely reason why you are getting this error is because the `--genesis` parameter is now deprecated and has been replaced with an `init` parameter.

See [geth init, what are the arguments?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/geth-init-what-are-the-arguments) for details on how to use the `init` parameter to initialise your private blockchain before being able to use it.

---

### Update 20/07/2016

From [`geth` Command Line Options - Init](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options#init):

> **Init**
>
> With the init command it is possible to create a chain with a custom genesis block and chain configuration (currently only the homestead transition block can be configured). It respects the `--datadir` argument and accepts a JSON file describing the chain configuration.
>
> ```
> geth --datadir <some/location/where/to/create/chain> init genesis.json
> ```
>
> Example genesis.json file:
>
> ```
> {
>     "config": {
>             "homesteadBlock": "10"
>     },
>     "nonce": "0",
>     "difficulty": "0x20000",
>     "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
>     "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>     "timestamp": "0x00",
>     "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>     "extraData": "0x",
>     "gasLimit": "0x2FEFD8",
>     "alloc": {}
> }
> ```
>
> To use the created chain start geth with:
>
> ```
> geth --datadir <some/location/where/to/create/chain>
> ```

Comment: Yes it is a version problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error i am able to reproduce is,

```
####################################################################
#                                                                  #
# --genesis is deprecated. Switch to use 'geth init /path/to/file' #
#                                                                  #
####################################################################
```

Try this, it will work.

```
geth --identity "Prashant" --rpc --rpcport "8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "chaindata" --port "30303" --nodiscover --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --autodag --networkid 1900 --nat "any" init /path/to/genesis.json console
```

Comment: This will work but it won't start a private blockchain because path to genesis file is not mentioned in your command. Removing `--genesis` command is not the expected solution here. It should be replaced with `init`.

Comment: @varm yeah, i explained it now.

Comment: @varm I added path to genesis using init and it's working good. The basic reason was genesis parameter was replaced with init