# Geth 1.4.10 invalid command line parameters

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I've upgraded my **geth** client to version **1.4.10-stable-5f55d95a** (from 1.3.5) and now it won't run with the following command line arguments (the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options#init) is lackluster when it comes to describing the **init** parameter):

```
geth --datadir "./data_dir" --networkid 13 --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc --maxpeers 0 init "gen.josn" --etherbase "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" --mine --minerthreads 2
```

which worked in 1.3.5.

I've tried the following variations:

```
geth --mine --minerthreads 2 --datadir "./data_dir" --networkid 13 --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc --maxpeers 0 init "gen.json"
```

which gives:

```
I0727 11:44:43.892926 ethdb/database.go:82] Alloted 16MB cache and 16 file handles to single_bootstrap_node_geth/chaindata
I0727 11:44:43.917096 core/genesis.go:92] Genesis block already in chain. Writing canonical number
I0727 11:44:43.917411 cmd/geth/main.go:299] successfully wrote genesis block and/or chain rule set: 2279317df6aed704d8d46771ed06fbe4b7a935f7005d341b091b7957bc374def
```

and also running as:

```
geth init "gen.json" --mine --minerthreads 2 --datadir "./data_dir" --networkid 13 --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc --maxpeers 0
```

which gives:

```
Incorrect Usage.

init [arguments...]

The init command initialises a new genesis block and definition for the network.
This is a destructive action and changes the network in which you will be
participating.


flag provided but not defined: -mine
```

Where can I find the documentation of version 1.4.10?

Comment: I've deleted the answer I posted before as it was clearly wrong - you'd already tried the suggestion. I'll have a look at the issue in the second command...

Answer (score 2):

According to the results of your second command, it looks like you're already running on a private blockchain. If that's the case, you don't need to give the `init` command again. Just the `--datadir` and `--networkid` commands will suffice.

```
Incorrect Usage.

init [arguments...]
```

The `--datadir` command should appear before the `init` command. [Source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7208/2460)

```
flag provided but not defined: -mine
```

Sometimes, when you copy paste the command, `--` will be replaced by `-` which might cause this error. To be sure, either type in the command or check it after copying.

Comment: I've managed to get it running. I had to setup the block chain using init and then run geth as a miner over it (pointing it to the directory in which the block chain was initiated).

Comment: Cool. I usually start/stop miner from the JavaScript console. I think it's easier.

Comment: In my setup I have a bash script that initializes the block chain once, starts mining, waits a little and finally launches geth IPC.