# Geth private network not starting

Tags: go-ethereum

I am setting up a private ethereum network (which I have done before), then I noticed that the flags have changed on geth as well as the removal of the genesis flag all together.

I changed the flags accordingly to what is below but when it goes to load up I only get the following message without the console starting up properly.

```
geth init ./UTSGenesis.json networkid "1100" maxpeers 20 port 3000 console

I0816 09:34:47.826895 ethdb/database.go:82] Allotted 16MB cache and 16  
file handles to /home/james/.ethereum/chaindata
I0816 09:34:47.894232 core/genesis.go:92] Genesis block already in   
chain. Writing canonical number
I0816 09:34:47.894507 cmd/geth/main.go:300] successfully wrote genesis  
block and/or chain rule set: f9deb7b6dc5fda52360cbab7f402b01ca4b76ff3112bdcce7f076d1b374d324c
```

As you can see, the console wont load up and it just quits out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try working on a different `--datadir`? Can you post a more detailed output? Was there no message after this?

Answer (score 3):

Using the `geth init` is a two part process.

The first is to initialise the blockchain with your parameters:

```
geth init ./UTSGenesis.json
```

The second is to run the node software on your newly created blockchain data. Note the `--` before the options:

```
geth --networkid "1100" --maxpeers 20 --port 3000 console
```

See also:

- [Geth --genesis is giving Invalid Usage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7206/geth-genesis-is-giving-invalid-usage/7208#7208)
- [geth init, what are the arguments?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/geth-init-what-are-the-arguments/2643#2643)