# Change private genesis state

Tags: go-ethereum

I have created a private network by Geth follow this tutorial on [github](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#operating-a-private-network). Now I want to add `“byzantiumBlock：1000”` to config block of `genesis.json`.

Will I get a new network and lose all blocks of my old network after I execute the command `geth init path/to/genesis.json` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the genesis block, then you'll be changing the block hash. With this you'll render the rest of the blockchain invalid.

> UPDATE: However there are field in the genesis block that do not contribute to the block hash and thus would not require the following

A new genesis block will require a new chain being built. On MacOS, the `get init <path to genesis>` command locks the `/Users/[user]/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata` folder by default. This would be shared by different nodes if you didn't explicitly specify a different `datadir`.

What is the `datadir`? - *It's a data directory for the databases and keystore associated with a node, in other words, a location where to create the blockchain*.

**Example:**

```
geth --datadir <path_of_data_directory> init <path_of_genesis_file>
```

An example value of the `<path_of_data_directory>` could be `Library/Ethereum/aCoolDataDirectoryName`. Then within that directory you'll have the following:

[image: contents of new datadir]

By specifying a different `datadir`, you'll be able to keep your old blockchain but create a new one with your new config.

#### Sources:

[Command Line Options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) 
[Related Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/geth-init-what-are-the-arguments)

Comment: The old blocks can be retained if the change of configs of genesis file is compatible.

Comment: In that case I'm assuming the the 'config' field isn't included into the block hash?

Comment: Yes, it is not included into the block hash, see SetupGenesisBlock method in core\genesis.go, there is a CheckCompatible logic at bottom of the method.

Comment: @XLeo cool, that’s a good find!