# How to change Geth PoA Clique block sealing time?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have used puppeth to generate genesis file in which I set sealing time to 30 seconds. I have set up one miner. Now, I want to change the sealing time to 5 seconds. How can I do that on same blockchain? I am using geth as my node.

Comment: Would be interesting to know where the clique specific config is stored...

Answer (score 1):

Can't provide guaranteed answer, but here are some ideas for you to try:

Check this answer [Change private genesis state](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30190/change-private-genesis-state)

In short it requires changing the genesis file and reinit the blockchain, because the period is a constant, but ...

clique -> period is inside the config section, so changing it may be one of the exceptions mentioned

Another suggestion is to try with modifying the config file generated with 'geth --options dumpconfig' if it contains the Clique parameters